# LTSpice AC analysis and DC analysis don't agree?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, ltspice, resonance, transient

I have a simple circuit pi circuit.  When I do the math and subsequently run the simulation on LTSpice, I get a similar answer - the resonance occurs at f= 217447Hz (math), 217450(LSpice).

[image]

The error log shows the following measurements:

```
.meas AC maxVout MAX mag(V(vout))
.meas AC resFreq when mag(V(vout))=maxVout*.99999999
.meas AC BW TRIG mag(V(vout))=maxVout/sqrt(2) RISE=1 TARG mag(V(vout))=maxVout/sqrt(2) FALL=last
.meas AC resQ PARAM 10^((resfreq/(bw))/20)    **this result is in decimal, but displays as dB in the error log file.
```

When I run a transient analysis, with the voltage source set  up as sine wave as $$ 1\cdot Sin(2\cdot\pi\cdot 217450\cdot t)$$, my expectation is the that output at node **vout** would be around 8.33V (10^(18.4138/20)volts).  However, the output of the transient response, the maximum amplitude of **vout** is around 2.1V volts:

[image]

What's going on?  Has anyone else run into something like this?

To check, I used Mathematica to plot the time domain output of my circuit's transfer function (convolved with the input sine wave source -ie, set Vin in my transfer function as a sine wave of frequency 217450 in the laplace domain, and then took the inverse laplace), I get something like I'd expect:

[image]

I don't know why LTSpice is not giving me the same answer ---I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: +1 for doubting yourself and your usage of the tool, instead of blaming the tool.

Comment: I always hesitate to blame the tool....;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, if a transient simulation isn't giving expected results, decrease the maximum time step.

I was able to reproduce your results with the default settings.

But when I set the maximum time step to 0.1 us, I get much closer to the expected results:

[image]

(n002 is the voltage source output terminal)

When I reduce the maximum timestep to 0.02 us I get very close to the theoretical amplitude:

[image]

Comment: piece of cake!  thank you for your quick response.....this was driving me nuts!!

Comment: Seems that larger timestep lowers the resonant frequency slightly. With default timestep I got 8.3V at 215900 Hz.

Comment: @jrive The main reason behind this is due to the very high quality factor (you have no load). That means high derivatives of the slopes which, in turn, mean that the \$\text{e}^{-b_1t},\,b_1\rightarrow 0\$ term takes a lot to converge. If you had used a lower Q, smaller timesteps would have not been necessary.